# Rendering glitches with Angular/Phonegap + CSS Transitions on Nexus 4

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm working on an app that's built using Angular 1.0.8 & Cordova 3.1 to support iOS & Android. I'm giving a general description since some information is proprietary, but hopefully it'll be enough to explain.

I'm struggling to fix a bug we've seen where one page, which contains a chart built with  (using chart.js), renders incorrectly on the Nexus 4. The test device we have is running Android 4.2.2, though the bug has been seen on other Nexus 4 devices; but not on other Android devices. The chart will either display twice, with one chart overlapping another, or it will fail to display at all. Either way, opening and closing our navigation menu (which is an off-canvas menu using JS & CSS3 translate3d and transitions to function) seems to reset the view and the chart appears properly.

I have incrementally added/removed CSS for the entire app, and still cannot pinpoint what exactly is causing this rendering issue. If I remove position:relative, width declarations, and float declarations from other elements on the page (not the element containing the chart in question), then the chart seems to display properly; however, this is not a viable solution.

**Things I Have Done:**

- Set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in our manifest file
- Removed typically problematic CSS properties (box-shadows, border-radius, transitions and translate3d, etc.); issue still persists
- Tried several methods known to help with flickering related to CSS transitions, such as -webkit-backface-visibility: none, -webkit-perspective: 1000, -webkit-transform-style: preserve3d, and others. None have resolved this issue.

I have seen other rendering glitches throughout this app that have been resolved with the above adjustments; however, the chart rendering issue remains unaffected.

Again, *this only occurs on the Nexus 4*. Unfortunately, it is a device I need to support, and this bug creates a substantial UI block; users can't read the chart data.

At this point I'm not even quite sure where to focus my trouble-shooting efforts. Any assistance, any suggestions, are appreciated; hopefully someone mentions something that helps clarify what's happening on this device. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding my answer based on the comments in this thread: code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474. (bug related to Android's rendering of canvas elements in versions >4. overflow: hidden on all parents of the canvas element seems to fix it in many cases, however that wasn't an option for me, so I had to use #41 (adjusting element opacity before and after rendering). Finally fixed this bug.